# Iterate through split string by another string

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash script to parse data returned by a this command :

```
openvpn --show-pkcs11-ids /usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so
```

The typical output is :

```
The following objects are available for use.
Each object shown below may be used as parameter to
--pkcs11-id option please remember to use single quote mark.

Certificate
       DN:             XXX
       Serial:         XXXX
       Serialized id:  XXXX

Certificate
       DN:             XXXX
       Serial:         XXXX
       Serialized id:  XXXX

Certificate
       DN:             XXXXX
       Serial:         XXXX
       Serialized id:  XXXX
```

I want to get an array in bash containing 3 elements : the 3 "Certificate" blocks. I tried a lot of method of splitting but all of them only output an echo command, not an actual array.

Any ideas ?

Thx !

Comment: What would this array look like? I can't imagine anything but a multi-dimensional array, but that wouldn't be supported in bash. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Welcome! Please show us the bash script you came up so far with.

Comment: @JNevill I don't especially need an array, for a I want to for loop that iterates through the 3 certificates

Answer (score 2):

This is one where it would be much simpler and (much much faster) to use `awk`. `awk` provide arrays and is much more capable at processing input records than `read`. With `awk` you simply write rules to be applied to each line of input. In your case you just need to recognize whether the line begins with `"DN:"`, `"Serial:"`, or `"Serialized"`. You can then store the associated value in a separate array, say arrays `dn`, `serial`, and `serid`. To accomplish this in `awk` you need nothing more than:

```
awk '
    $1 == "Certificate" {n++};              # increment n
    NF == 2 {                               # fill dn & serial array
        $1 == "DN:" && dn[n]=$2
        $1 == "Serial:" && serial[n]=$2
    }
    NF == 3 {                               # fill serid array
        $1 == "Serialized" && serid[n]=$3
    }
END {   # output results
    print "\nDN:\t\tSerial:\t\tSerialized id:"
    for (i in dn) print dn[i], "\t\t", serial[i], "\t\t", serid[i]
}' file
```

Above if the first field (`$1`) is `"Certificate"` you just increment a counter. If there are 2 fields in the line (`NF == 2`) then you check if the line begins with `"DN:"` or `"Serial"` and add the 2nd field to the proper array. If the line has 3-fields (`"Serialized", "id:"` and your value) you store the value in the `serid` array.

With all values stored, you can iterate over the arrays in the `END` rule, providing any output you need. Above it simply outputs the content in tabular form. You can just copy/middle-mouse-paste in the command line to test.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '
>     $1 == "Certificate" {n++};              # increment n
>     NF == 2 {                               # fill dn & serial array
>         $1 == "DN:" && dn[n]=$2
>         $1 == "Serial:" && serial[n]=$2
>     }
>     NF == 3 {                               # fill serid array
>         $1 == "Serialized" && serid[n]=$3
>     }
> END {   # output results
>     print "\nDN:\t\tSerial:\t\tSerialized id:"
>     for (i in dn) print dn[i], "\t\t", serial[i], "\t\t", serid[i]
> }' file

DN:             Serial:         Serialized id:
XXX              XXXX            XXXX
XXXX             XXXX            XXXX
XXXXX            XXXX            XXXX
```

For large file processing, `awk` will be *orders of magnitude* faster that looping in a shell script. Let me know if this satisfies your needs of if you need additional help.

**Edit Per-Comment**

If you are dealing with a file that has mixed tabs and spaces being used a separators, that can present problem with `awk` parsing using a default *field separator* (space). To consider a sequence of mixed spaces/tabs as a separator, with GNU `awk` you can provide a regular expression for the separator. For instance considering a sequence of one or more spaces or tabs can be specified as `-F'[ \t]+'`. The example below makes use of the separator. (note: the field numbers will change as a result)

```
awk -F'[ \t]+' '
    $1 == "Certificate" {n++};              # increment n
    NF == 3 {                               # fill dn & serial array
        $2 == "DN:" && dn[n]=$3
        $2 == "Serial:" && serial[n]=$3
    }
    NF == 4 {                               # fill serid array
        $2 == "Serialized" && serid[n]=$4
    }
END {   # output results
    print "\nDN:\t\tSerial:\t\tSerialized id:"
    for (i in dn) print dn[i], "\t\t", serial[i], "\t\t", serid[i]
}' f
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your same data you would then have:

```
$ awk -F'[ \t]+' '
>     $1 == "Certificate" {n++};              # increment n
>     NF == 3 {                               # fill dn & serial array
>         $2 == "DN:" && dn[n]=$3
>         $2 == "Serial:" && serial[n]=$3
>     }
>     NF == 4 {                               # fill serid array
>         $2 == "Serialized" && serid[n]=$4
>     }
> END {   # output results
>     print "\nDN:\t\tSerial:\t\tSerialized id:"
>     for (i in dn) print dn[i], "\t\t", serial[i], "\t\t", serid[i]
> }' f

DN:             Serial:         Serialized id:
XXX              XXXX            XXXX
XXXX             XXXX            XXXX
XXXXX            XXXX            XXXX
```

Not knowing what the space/tab makeup of your posted text actually is, this should handle either case.

**Further Update Posting Input Contents Taken From Question**

The following is the input file `f` (or `file`) used with the examples above. It was taken from your question, but there is no guarantee the space/tab translation is the same give the copy/paste into the question. The last example above should handle it regardless. The only other caveat is if you have a file with DOS line ending you are feeding to `awk` -- it won't work. You can check by running the utility `file yourfilename` and it will report is DOS `CRLF` line endings are present. You can then use `dos2unix yourfilename` to correct the problem and convert the file to Unix/POSIX line endings.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat f
The following objects are available for use.
Each object shown below may be used as parameter to
--pkcs11-id option please remember to use single quote mark.

Certificate
       DN:             XXX
       Serial:         XXXX
       Serialized id:  XXXX

Certificate
       DN:             XXXX
       Serial:         XXXX
       Serialized id:  XXXX

Certificate
       DN:             XXXXX
       Serial:         XXXX
       Serialized id:  XXXX
```

**Hexdump of Contents**

```
$ hexdump -Cv f
00000000  54 68 65 20 66 6f 6c 6c  6f 77 69 6e 67 20 6f 62  |The following ob|
00000010  6a 65 63 74 73 20 61 72  65 20 61 76 61 69 6c 61  |jects are availa|
00000020  62 6c 65 20 66 6f 72 20  75 73 65 2e 0a 45 61 63  |ble for use..Eac|
00000030  68 20 6f 62 6a 65 63 74  20 73 68 6f 77 6e 20 62  |h object shown b|
00000040  65 6c 6f 77 20 6d 61 79  20 62 65 20 75 73 65 64  |elow may be used|
00000050  20 61 73 20 70 61 72 61  6d 65 74 65 72 20 74 6f  | as parameter to|
00000060  0a 2d 2d 70 6b 63 73 31  31 2d 69 64 20 6f 70 74  |.--pkcs11-id opt|
00000070  69 6f 6e 20 70 6c 65 61  73 65 20 72 65 6d 65 6d  |ion please remem|
00000080  62 65 72 20 74 6f 20 75  73 65 20 73 69 6e 67 6c  |ber to use singl|
00000090  65 20 71 75 6f 74 65 20  6d 61 72 6b 2e 0a 0a 43  |e quote mark...C|
000000a0  65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61  74 65 0a 20 20 20 20 20  |ertificate.     |
000000b0  20 20 44 4e 3a 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |  DN:           |
000000c0  20 20 58 58 58 0a 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 53 65 72  |  XXX.       Ser|
000000d0  69 61 6c 3a 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 58 58 58  |ial:         XXX|
000000e0  58 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 53 65 72 69 61 6c 69  |X.       Seriali|
000000f0  7a 65 64 20 69 64 3a 20  20 58 58 58 58 0a 0a 43  |zed id:  XXXX..C|
00000100  65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61  74 65 0a 20 20 20 20 20  |ertificate.     |
00000110  20 20 44 4e 3a 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |  DN:           |
00000120  20 20 58 58 58 58 0a 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 53 65  |  XXXX.       Se|
00000130  72 69 61 6c 3a 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 58 58  |rial:         XX|
00000140  58 58 0a 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 53 65 72 69 61 6c  |XX.       Serial|
00000150  69 7a 65 64 20 69 64 3a  20 20 58 58 58 58 0a 0a  |ized id:  XXXX..|
00000160  43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63  61 74 65 0a 20 20 20 20  |Certificate.    |
00000170  20 20 20 44 4e 3a 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |   DN:          |
00000180  20 20 20 58 58 58 58 58  0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |   XXXXX.       |
00000190  53 65 72 69 61 6c 3a 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |Serial:         |
000001a0  58 58 58 58 0a 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 53 65 72 69  |XXXX.       Seri|
000001b0  61 6c 69 7a 65 64 20 69  64 3a 20 20 58 58 58 58  |alized id:  XXXX|
000001c0  0a                                                |.|
000001c1
```

Let me know the results of your file examination.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !
Unfortunaly, that's not working :/ It outputs me "DN:  Serial:  Serialized id:" (with no data). I tried your exact command and replaced "file" by "test.txt", a file containing the ouput of my openvpn command. Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Do you have `tabs` instead of spaces between the data? That would explain it. Hold on I'll give you something to try.

Comment: @Hyrla add `{ gsub (/\t/, " ") }` above the `$1 == "Certificate" {n++};` line to handle the `tabs` in your file (it will convert them to spaces, so it will then handle either `tabs` or `spaces`)

Comment: Sadly it's still not working :/ It seems that the output is made out of spaces, not tabs

Comment: You have the option of forcing the *field separator* which depending on if you are dealing with mixed spaces/tabs will help. Ill drop an edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your edits. Sadly it's still not working :( I really don't know why. My output doesn't seem to have mixed tab and space but only space... Can you post your "f" file to see it ?

Comment: @Hyrla - I'm beginning to suspect you have a DOS line-endings issue with your input file. See the update posting the requesting file information, as well as notes on how to confirm your line-endings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWK to do that. It is a tool specifically created for transforming table-like output.

```sh
openvpn --show-pkcs11-ids /usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so | grep 'Certificate\|DN:\|Serial:\|Serialized id:' | awk -v RS="Certificate" '{print $2,$4,$7}'
```

Explanation:

> grep 'Certificate\|DN:\|Serial:\|Serialized id:' - Choose only interesting lines of output
>   awk -v RS="Certificate" '{print $2,$4,$7}' - See below comment

**Comment**: AWK enables you to change the record separator using "-v RS=" parameter. By default it is a newline, so each line of the file is a record, but it can be changed to any string e.g. "Certificate".

Output is not an array, but every certificate is described in separate line you can further pipe to another tool.